# Sharepoint 2013 search results custom grouping display template

Tags: search, grouping, sharepoint-2013, display-templates

I am trying to implement custom grouping for search result items. I would like to group them by a managed property, but without using result blocks (query rules). The idea is to sort the results by the property and then compare the current item (ctx.CurrentItem) with the previous item using ctx.CurrentItem.ParentTableReference. If a new property value is detected we insert a new 'group header' (just some simple html). The problem is the ParentTableReference is undefined. Shouldn't there be such a property in current item object?
I'm implementing this in a custom search result item display template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all items in result table, you can get `ctx.CurrentGroup.ResultRows`.